# Add option for "No notable claim" when flagging for mod attention

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notability, flagging

Thought this might help the mods: When flagging for mod attention is it possible to add this as an option?

Example question (like you need it!): [Instant, painless amputation via high-pressure steam](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10068/instant-painless-amputation-via-high-pressure-steam)

Comment: I would add a specific close reason for non notable claim as well.

Comment: Doesn't the "Off Topic" option cover this?

Comment: Note the new off-topic close reason.

Answer (score 5):

Questions without notable claims are off-topic, I see no reason for a special flag option. There is nothing different about handling those flags that would require a different flag reason.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought i'd throw it out there.